# How to play AnimationPlayer in script once. Godot Engine

Tags: godot

When I hold the button the animation starts loop and playing again, but I want when I hold the button, the animation plays once, and when I let it go, the animation also plays once only in the opposite direction.

How can I do it?

Please, help!

#### My code example:

```
extends RigidBody2D


func _physsics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_jump'):
        $Leg/LegAnimation.play('LegMove');
    else:
        $Leg/LegAnimation.play_backwards('LegMove');
```

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

You can uncheck the animation loop option on the animation editor or you can add the animation_finished event to the animation with this code:

```
func _on_Animation_animation_finished(anim_name):
    $Animation.stop()
```